# Create a text file using PrintWriter

Tags: java, android

```
PrintWriter p;
    try {
        p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("xp.mdb"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }

    p.println("mytext");
    p.close();
```

I'm new to Android programming and don't quite understand how writing to files work. I want to create a new file and write some text to it. The above code works on Windows but on Android I just keep getting FileNotFoundException.

How can I make it create the file if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the file in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or (on Android 4.4+) [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Passing a bare filename does not work on Android.

Comment: I see. However, now I have another problem. The method which does the writing is static, and I can't get context. Is it safe if I use an absolute path like /data/data/my.app.package/mytext.txt ? Just tried this and it works.

Comment: @Kidades: "Is it safe if I use an absolute path like /data/data/my.app.package/mytext.txt ?" -- no. That will fail on about ~1 billion devices (all Android 4.2+ tablets and all Android 5.0+ phones) when the app is being run by somebody other than the primary device user. I seem to recall additional reasons why that will fail on Android 6.0+ devices, though the details escape me right now. Never hardcode paths.

Comment: @Kidades: "I can't get context" -- pass one into the static method. Everything that you do started with some `Context` (activity, service, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare - and that illustrates one of the reasons that `static` methods are inferior - you pretty much *have to* pass the context as a parameter.  (OK ... exaggeration.  I can think of 2 other ways, but they are not general)

Comment: @CommonsWare: Will new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir() + "/file.txt") work on every device?

Comment: @Kidades: I recommend `new FileWriter(new File(context.getFilesDir(), "file.txt"))`, as that way it works no matter whether `getFilesDir()` returns a value with a trailing `/` or not.